# inheriting controller in angular1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With angular1.6 I have the situation where with different views around 60% controller logic is same. In that case, how can I apply inheritance to the controller logic? 
I went through to http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/ and http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/03/25/angularjs-a-better-way-to-implement-a-base-controller

and wrote a sample code to apply in my case but that is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.6.6/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">

<div class="" ng-controller="Child1 as ctrl1">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="ctrl1.clickMethod()">ClickA</button>
</div>

<div class="" ng-controller="Child2 as ctrl2">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="ctrl2.clickMethod()">ClickB</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  angular.module('test',[])
    .controller('Base', function(){

      var sharedMethod = function(arg) {
        console.log('shared method called with ' + arg);
      }
    })
    .controller('Child1', function($scope, $controller) {

      $controller('Base', { $scope : $scope});
      var ctrl1 = this;
      var clickMethod = function() {
        this.sharedMethod(41);
      };
    })
    .controller('Child2', function($scope, $controller) {

      $controller('Base', { $scope : $scope});
      var ctrl2 = this;
      var clickMethod = function() {
          this.sharedMethod(42);
      };
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`sharedMethod` is the thing which I want to share with two different views, having a different controller.

Moreover, in this example, I had created the controller(`Base`) which doesn't have any view, is it possible with angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code in the way you are have defined your functions you need to make the following change :

```
 angular.module('test',[]).controller('Base', function($scope){

 $scope.sharedMethod = function(arg) {
    console.log('shared method called with ' + arg);
  }
})
.controller('Child1', function($scope, $controller) {

  $controller('Base', { $scope : $scope});
  var ctrl1 = this;
  ctrl1.clickMethod = function() {
    $scope.sharedMethod(41);
  };
})
.controller('Child2', function($scope, $controller) {

  $controller('Base', { $scope : $scope});
  var ctrl2 = this;
  ctrl2.clickMethod = function() {
      $scope.sharedMethod(42);
  }

});
```

you have to call functions properly to make it work .

Comment: thank you vertika it's working I need to understand more about how `$scope` works.

Comment: what if I want to move a call to a shared method in html, like this <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="ctrl2.sharedMethod(11)">ClickB</button> how can I do that? without defining in the controller.

Comment: Ok you can do it totally . You will need to make few changes  .  dont give your function in ctrl1 then as its already available in $scope because of inheritance and sinc its available in $scope you can use it directly in your html .  so the change would be in your controller :  .controller('Child2', function($scope, $controller) {

      $controller('Base', { $scope : $scope});
     

});  And in your html while calling the function   :   <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="sharedMethod('42')">ClickB</button>